# Text drawn in 3D on Canvas

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

How can I display text as 3D on a Canvas in Flutter? One way I've thought of is to replicate the text multiple times but display each replicant as an offset from the original text. The problem with that is that you won't be able to distinguish the edges because there wouldn't be any shadows/lighting.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: I did a prototype where I was able to run three.js inside a webview, but I couldn't draw it on a Canvas. Try this [demo](https://github.com/andreibosco/flutter_threejs_test). There's also [this](https://github.com/wasabia/three_dart), but I'm not sure if it's able to draw on a Canvas.